# Zebra Barcode prints, but doesn't scan

Tags: qr-code, barcode, barcode-scanner, zebra-printers, code128

I need to print a 17 digit barcode. Values are coming from parameters. Barcode is printed ok, all parameters are there, it looks good, but it doesn't scan anything with the scanner.

This is what i tried:

^XA
^BY2,2,5^FO05,800
^BCN,100,Y,N,N^FV#01/ProductionNumber;02/02;03/ProductionNumber;04/Application;05/param_ProdNumber;07/10#^FS
^XZ

Image: https://ibb.co/2nFNvdR?fbclid=IwAR0H5ptpw0uTsiqFpGLhelp5AXABvZb1XBaHl0CFKD8XYsGb2lW0OKHLyiw

Comment: Without seeing a picture of the barcode, it is hard to say what is wrong.  But it could be two things.  First, your scanner may not be configured for code128.  And second, the bar code is being "cropped" by the printer and not printing its full length.  This can happen when the print width is defined shorter than the width of the label.

Comment: Hi, thank's for your answer. I added a picture, the barcode is printed fully. It may be that scanner it's not configured to code 128, but i think phone apps for barcode scanning include all types of codes.

Comment: Looking at that picture, it appears there is some "inkspread" that is causing the bars to be too wide.  (Notice how they change width near the top of the bars.)  Assuming this is a standard zebra thermal printer, you should try decreasing the darkness setting for the print head and/or increase the print speed.

Answer (score 1):

Your printer is lopping off the right 3 characters. That's the number 5, the checksum, and the stop character.

[image]

Comment: Hi, tjank you for answering. How can i stop the lopping of the 3 characters?

Comment: There is probably a margin setting for the Zebra printer or the software depending on who is shortening the graphic. Since the lettering is off center to the visible part of the barcode, I am guessing the graphic rendering is working and I suspect the printer has a setting for right margin that is too small. You can probably use ZPL or printer control codes to enable full left-to-right edge printing.